# Why does my custom 404 page return '404 ok' response in Django?

Tags: python, django

I've to render a custom 404 template with django.
I decided to start on the basic of it:

```
def custom_page_not_found(request):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

And I'm pretty curious to know why I can't have a "404 not found". If I don't use the handler404 from urls.py, I will have the blank 404 page with the current status.
But not when I want to have a custom template.

Does anyone know why? (django 1.7.11)

Comment: If all you want to do is use a custom template for your 404 page, then you do not need to set `handler404` or create a custom view. Just stick your `404.html` template in your templates directory.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But if I need to use a custom view for whatever purpose, can't I have a proper `404 not found` http response?

Comment: Of course you can. But your question is quite confusing; there is no such thing as "404 ok", did you mean it is returning "200 ok"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django 1.9+, changing the [`status_code`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.status_code) (e.g. to 404) will change the [`reason_phrase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.reason_phrase) if it is not set (e.g. to 'not found'). However, you are using an older version of Django, so you would have to change the `reason_phrase` manually otherwise it will remain as 'ok'.

It would be easier to set the status when creating the response.

```
def custom_page_not_found(request):
    return render_to_response('404.html', {},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request),
                              status=404)
```

Since the `render_to_response` shortcut is obsolete, it would be better to use `render` instead.

```
def custom_page_not_found(request):
    return render(request, '404.html', {}, status=404)
```

Comment: Man, you are my sunshine of the day (London weather). I was stuck on it for so long. 
Thank you so much!